# How to insert elements in array in reverse order using for loop

Tags: java, arrays

getting output as 0123456789 but i want to store it in reverse order . i know i am missing something please help. So the order would be in 9876543210

```
 for(int i  = a.length-1;  i>=0 ; i--){

        a[i]  = i;

    }
```

Comment: `a[a.length-i] = i`

Comment: @depperm thanx this was what i was looking for... but what was the problem with above approach..

Comment: @AjayKumarSinha it is still incorrect because you're only basically numbering elements, not really reversing it. If you want any reversed array check my answer.

Comment: A simple example to show the fault. when `i = 9(a.length-1) >> a[9] = 9, like this a[8]  = 8, a[7] = 7,...,a[2] = 2, a[1] = 1, a[0] = 0`. See the issue, numbers are added in ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

Use `a[a.length-i-1] = i` inside your loop.

You're approach sets `i` element to be `i`, instead of the reverse which would be `length-i-1`

Comment: this code will fail when i becomes 0. Suppose array is of length 10 and then when i becomes 0, your expression will become a[10] = 0  this will give exception. It should be a[a.length -i -1] = i

Answer (score 0):

You want it in reverse order so first value should go into last array element.
You should do it like shown below in snippet:

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    int a[]=new int[10];
    for(int i  = a.length-1;  i>=0 ; i--){

        a[a.length-i-1]  = i;

    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

Comment: @depperm No it won't because in that case i will be -1 and for loop will not execute.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code like below

```
for(int i  = 0;  i<a.length ; i++){
       a[i]  = a.lenght-i-1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Create the new array and store the reversed value in the new array.
>   try this:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String []args){
        int[] a = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
        int[] b = new int[a.length];
        int j=0;
        for(int i  = a.length-1;  i>=0 ; i--){
            b[j]  = a[i];
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should reverse an array:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= a.length / 2; i++){
    int tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[a.length - i - 1];
    a[a.length - i - 1] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: thanx for your response.